# While installation of GDAL

Tags: gdal

can any one solve this issue? what is the error mentioning  is out of my knowledge.

```
d\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\osgeo_utils\samples
      running build_ext
      building 'osgeo._gdal' extension
      building 'osgeo._ogr' extension
      building 'osgeo._gdalconst' extension
      building 'osgeo._osr' extension
      building 'osgeo._gnm' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for GDAL
Failed to build GDAL
ERROR: Could not build wheels for GDAL, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

```
I try to install GDAL in two different methods , using pip and also downloaded and gave the path in project settings but facing trouble .
```